# How can I open modal automatically with tailwind element's component?

Tags: tailwind-elements

I want to open a timeout/session modal after a while. But reading the [documentation](https://tw-elements.com/docs/standard/components/modal/).
I have not found a solution. It seems that it is only possible by clicking on button or cta!
Has anyone had the same need as can help me? I'am using vanilla javascript version.